# How to add a URL in the description field in Facebook by using dialog/feed javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, ios, html, facebook-graph-api

There is a requirement to post messages from our website. I am using the below code for achieving the same.

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=123050457758183&source =www.google.com&  link=www.google.com&picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&  name=Facebook%20Dialogs&  caption=Reference%20Documentation&  description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users&  message=Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!&  redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response
```

Everything is working fine. I want to add a URL like "For more information click here - www.somesite.com". I tried to put href in the description body but Facebook does not recognize it as a link.
 We have both iOS and HTML5 application and in iOS, it is possible to put link in Description. So was wondering why javascript does not support this.

The below code does the same in iOS.

```
NSDictionary *propertyValue = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"[(www.somesite.com)]",@"text",@"http://www.somesite.com",@"href", nil];
NSDictionary *properties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:propertyValue, @"For more information  click here",nil];
```

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript API **does** support this, but it's not well documented on the Facebook Developers site. I was finally able to get it working after reading this page:
[fbdevwiki.com/wiki/FB.ui](http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/FB.ui#method%3a_.27feed.27)

Here's sample of the JavaScript params that worked for me:

```
var params = {
method: 'feed',
name: 'Name Name Name',
link: 'http://www.website.com/',
picture: http://www.website.com/yourimage,
caption: 'Caption Caption Caption',
description: 'Get it from iTunes today',
properties: {'Download Free':{ text: 'My Fancy App', href: 'http://www.itunes.com/'}},
actions: [{name: 'Free iTunes Download', link: 'http://www.itunes.com/'}]
};
```

The "actions" parameter adds a link down by the "like" and "comment" links at the bottom of the post.

Comment: BTW, `action` is supported by android and iOS api too.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't have links to `description` or `caption` (you can place URL here but it wouldn't be link) and `message` property is deprecated (and even removed from documentation of [Feed Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)).

Instead you should use `link` property so `name` of the post will be pointing to.

BTW, Even if you will use Graph API to post content without showing it to user and add URL in the `message` it will not be displayed as link in most places user can see it. (beware that `message` is something that should be written by user, or it will be probably violation of [Platform Policies](http://developers.dev.facebook.com/policy/))

Comment: Thanks for the response. I made a mistake by saying "Messages".its the "Description". We have both iOS and HTML5 application and in iOS, it is possible to put link in Description. So was wondering why javascript does not support this.

Comment: @user1192248,  you should edit your original question to reflect the explanation in your comment above.

Comment: @JijuSomanath, it's possible, just the URL will not be link, actually it's not about JS-SDK but about Facebook trusting published content.

Comment: @JuicyScripter, its displaying as link.That is why my client is asking to implement this in HTML5 app.